# Access logs pattern change - JSESSIONID value is not picking up

Tags: tomcat

We have the below mentioned access log pattern

```
@server.xml @Tomcat %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %D %B %a %{JSESSIONID}
```

Please find the access logs generated below

> [23/Apr/2018:15:39:48 -0400] "GET /F5Health.htm HTTP/1.1" 302 123 0 30.96.252.61 ???{???JSESSIONID}

We are good with the HTTP/HTTPS code, RequestTime, Size, and RemoteIPHost but the JSESSIONID is not getting populated.

Comment: %{JSESSIONID} is not a valid attribute. Have a look at the [Extended Access Log Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Extended_Access_Log_Valve) which provides **x-H(requestedSessionId)**

Comment: You need to add JSESSIONID to the request headers for the tomcat to be able to grab it value and add it to the log. otherwise it you need the session ID use %S - User session ID

Comment: 1) Could you please provide the difference between JSESSIONID,User SessionID and requestedSessionID.                           2) Also please provide the JSESSIONID syntax to be added @web.xml .